# Do you like hats? (2014 Edition)

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Last year around Christmas time we had an awesome promotion in which hats for for gravatars were awarded for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/)
 to the promo from last year (and [the year before that](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* again because we all love hats, right? right?

This year we would need to **opt-out** if we don't want any of this haberdashery. For the purposes of a simple count, ***upvote*** this question to indicate you would like hats, and ***downvote*** this question if you don't want hats at all.

We've had a lot of fun with this promotion in the past, and I'm sure it's going to be fun again this time.

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

---

(Majority of content blatantly stolen from [freiheit](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/freiheit)'s copy of [waxeagle](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/wax-eagle)'s [post on meta.christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats).)

Comment: [*Don't be a hater... be a hatter! **Bring on the Hats!!!***](http://meta.moderators.stackexchange.com/a/192/42) ;)

Comment: It is always good to see that the Stack Exchange resources and the efforts of its dev team are directed to the truly important things. Why direct efforts towards for example the broken review audit system, when the devs' time could be better spent implementing hat graphics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will be getting hats again. Thanks for your input.

Comment: And [the event will run from December 15th, 2014, to January 4th, 2015](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244105).